# Is ory/keto support Contextual and Time-based authorization?

Tags: authorization, ory

I have a scenario where I want to restrict access to a document based on his IP address using [ory/keto](https://github.com/ory/keto) authorization service.

It looks like I can't achieve contextual attribute based authorization using ory/keto. I couldn't find any docs on that in ory/keto doc space. I tried few authorization check payloads to pass the dynamic attributes for the user. An example is provided below (I tried and it didn't work, ory/keto doesn't allow nested subject_sets).

```
{
    "namespace": "document",
    "object": "document",
    "relation": "view",
    "subject_set": {
        "namespace": "user",
        "object": "john",
        "relation": "is",
        "subject_set": {
            "namespace": "ip-address-range",
            "object": "0.0.0.10/11"
        }
    }
}
```

Can we achieve Contextual and Time-based authorization with ory/keto? If we can, can I get an example of how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue for this (which was probably the inspiration for Auth0/OpenFGA): https://github.com/ory/keto/issues/319
It is a cool feature but there is no implementation effort yet.